# Test application on all Windows OS's and architectures

Tags: .net, windows, testing, automation

We have to test our desktop application (.NET with WPF) on below versions of windows :

- Windows XP x86
- Windows XP x64
- Windows 7 x86
- Windows 7 x64
- Windows 8 x86
- Windows 8 x64

Each time we want to release we have to test whole application functionalists and its setup file on all versions of windows. 
I've installed all versions on virtual machine but it is still very time-consuming task. I am looking for a way to make whole or at least part of process automatic. 
Any Idea or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Use automated testing. It will still take a long time, but you can just let it run overnight.

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you please tell me more or a link for more description?

Comment: Not sure what more there is to say. Write a program that tests your program. [Test automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of automated test framework that were used in several projects I have worked on:

1. Automated QA TestComplete
2. IBM Rational Functional Tester
3. Selenium: open source, but only supports web application testing